# Why is my javascript sort function not producing the correct order?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a function that sorts courses (divs) based on an end date that is declared in a data attribute. The entire list of classes is sorting correct except one. I cannot figure out why it is not sorting it correctly. The March 24th is the first one in the sorted list.

I am guessing it is only looking at the "2" in "24" but I am not sure how to get around this, if it is the case.

HTML

```
 <button onClick="courseSort()">SORT</button>

    <div id="course-container" class="row pb-5 pt-5">
        <div class="class-item col-12 col-md-6 pb-4" data-class-start="1/1/2022" data-class-end="5/28/2022">
            <h5>May 28</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="class-item col-12 col-md-6 pb-4" data-class-start="2/8/2022" data-class-end="3/9/2022">
            <h5>Mar 9</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="class-item col-12 col-md-6 pb-4" data-class-start="1/1/2022" data-class-end="3/5/2022">
            <h5>Mar 5</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="class-item col-12 col-md-6 pb-4" data-class-start="1/1/2022" data-class-end="4/1/2022">
            <h5>Apr 1</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="class-item col-12 col-md-6 pb-4" data-class-start="2/19/2022" data-class-end="3/8/2022">
            <h5>Mar 8</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="class-item col-12 col-md-6 pb-4" data-class-start="2/19/2022" data-class-end="3/24/2022">
            <h5>Mar 24</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="class-item col-12 col-md-6 pb-4" data-class-start="1/1/2022" data-class-end="4/23/2022">
            <h5>Apr 23</h5> 
        </div>
        <div class="class-item col-12 col-md-6 pb-4" data-class-start="1/1/2022" data-class-end="4/30/2022">
            <h5>Apr 30</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
function sorter(a, b) {
    if (a.dataset.classEnd < b.dataset.classEnd)
        return -1;
    if (a.dataset.classEnd > b.dataset.classEnd)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
  
// Function to sort Data
function courseSort() {
    var course = document.querySelectorAll("[data-class-end]");
    var courseArray = Array.from(course);
    let sorted = courseArray.sort(sorter);
    sorted.forEach(e =>
        document.querySelector("#course-container").appendChild(e));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The `sorter` function correctly performs a lexicographic sort and your `forEach` correctly reappends elements in the sorted order. Dates are usually provided in the [ISO 8601 format](/q/9576860/4642212) to allow for easy sorting. I suggest you convert the dates to this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check function `sorter(a, b)`. When you're accessing for example `a.dataset.classEnd`, it's a string, not a date. You may want to do something like:

```
function sorter(a, b) {
  const [aDate, bDate] = [new Date(a.dataset.classEnd), new Date(b.dataset.classEnd)];
  if (aDate < bDate) return -1;
  if (aDate > bDate) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Also, you could simply do this like a one-liner instead of a separated function:

```
let sorted = courseArray.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.dataset.classEnd) - new Date(b.dataset.classEnd));
```

> I am guessing it is only looking at the "2" in "24" but I am not sure
> how to get around this, if it is the case.

Yes, that's exactly what was happening as you were comparing strings.

EDIT: As Sebastian Simon suggested in comments, you may like to change the format of your dates to allow sorting without really needing to convert the variables to date.

Comment: _“Note: Parsing of date strings with the `Date` constructor (and `Date.parse`, which works the same way) is **strongly discouraged** due to browser differences and inconsistencies.”_ — From the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#parameters).

Comment: See [Parsing a string to a date in JavaScript](/q/5619202/4642212). Something as “simple” as `const mdyDate = (dateString) => { const { year, month, date } = dateString.match(/(?<month>\d+)\/(?<date>\d+)\/(?<year>\d+)/)?.groups ?? {}; return new Date(year, month - 1, date); };` and then `.sort(({ dataset: { classEnd: a } }, { dataset: { classEnd: b } }) => mdyDate(a) - mdyDate(b))` is probably enough.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments, the true value of a date can be derived from the Date object. In the example below, the function `courseArray(nodeList)` will:

- convert the NodeList into an array run it through `.map()`

  ```
  [...nodeList].map(d => {...
  // [...nodeList] is the same as Array.from(nodeList)
  ```
- extract the value from `data-class-end` and convert it to ISO format

  ```
  let mmddyyyy = d.dataset.classEnd;
  let yyyymmdd = mmddyyyy.split('/');
  let yyyy = yyyymmdd.pop();
  yyyymmdd.unshift(yyyy);
  let ISO = yyyymmdd.join('-');
  // from mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd
  ```
- then it is converted to the number of milli-seconds since 1-1-1970 to the ISO date -- then it's added as `data-order` to the div and then the divs are reordered according to `data-order` value.

  ```
    let ms = Date.parse(ISO);
    d.dataset.order = ms;
    return d;
  }).sort((a, b) => a.dataset.order - b.dataset.order);
  ```

Also, the inline event handler was removed and a onevent property event handler was added. See why [inline event handlers are garbage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these).

```js
const courseArray = nodeList => {
  return [...nodeList].map(d => {
    let mmddyyyy = d.dataset.classEnd;
    let yyyymmdd = mmddyyyy.split('/');
    let yyyy = yyyymmdd.pop();
    yyyymmdd.unshift(yyyy);
    let ISO = yyyymmdd.join('-');
    let ms = Date.parse(ISO);
    d.dataset.order = ms;
    return d;
  }).sort((a, b) => a.dataset.order - b.dataset.order);
};

function courseSort() {
  const course = document.querySelectorAll(".class-item");

  let sorted = courseArray(course);
  sorted.forEach(e =>
    document.querySelector("#course-container").appendChild(e));
};

document.querySelector('button').onclick = courseSort;
```

```html
<button>SORT</button>

<div id="course-container" class="row pb-5 pt-5">
  <div class="class-item col-12 col-md-6 pb-4" data-class-start="1/1/2022" data-class-end="5/28/2022">
    <h5>May 28</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="class-item col-12 col-md-6 pb-4" data-class-start="2/8/2022" data-class-end="3/9/2022">
    <h5>Mar 9</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="class-item col-12 col-md-6 pb-4" data-class-start="1/1/2022" data-class-end="3/5/2022">
    <h5>Mar 5</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="class-item col-12 col-md-6 pb-4" data-class-start="1/1/2022" data-class-end="4/1/2022">
    <h5>Apr 1</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="class-item col-12 col-md-6 pb-4" data-class-start="2/19/2022" data-class-end="3/8/2022">
    <h5>Mar 8</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="class-item col-12 col-md-6 pb-4" data-class-start="2/19/2022" data-class-end="3/24/2022">
    <h5>Mar 24</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="class-item col-12 col-md-6 pb-4" data-class-start="1/1/2022" data-class-end="4/23/2022">
    <h5>Apr 23</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="class-item col-12 col-md-6 pb-4" data-class-start="1/1/2022" data-class-end="4/30/2022">
    <h5>Apr 30</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```